# Is it possible to add a version number to a file that will be visible in Properties/Details in windows explorer

Tags: c++, windows

I have an unmanaged C++ project where I am writing data to a custom file format that I have defined.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to add a header that is compatible with Windows Explorer so that a version number will be displayed, as in the example below showing a Windows font.

[image: Example]

The purpose of this is so that non-tech savvy users could simply right click and identify the version of the file, without having to open it in Notepad etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tom

Comment: to use a version resource you need PE format, i.e. exe or dll. however there is a chance that you can use OLE streams. or whatever it is that Explorer uses for custom attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot achieve this for a file in general. But if your file format stores a version information, you can teach the Windows Explorer to display it.

You have to write a *Shell Extension* for the Explorer, that can extract arbitrary information out of your files. This extension must be installed on the target computer and registered in the registry.

An excellent guide on how to write and register Shell Extensions can be found [here on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx). (Part VIII should cover what you need)

Answer (score 3):

The version information comes from [VERSIONINFO resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), attached to a binary file, such as .EXE or .DLL. So it is easy to link such resource into your build target, this resource is also editable.

However, this is limited to the binary executable files, and you cannot attach this resource information to arbitrary files (as you wanted), including such as text files.

Answer (score 2):

In VC just go to menu Project->AddResource and pick Version.

Comment: from what I understand that is for the .exe file that is built. I would like to add this info in on the fly to custom files I am creating within the program

Comment: A txt file for example has no resources inside. At least as far as i know.